# just return last row bold in mssql_fetch_array

Tags: php

I have a php code similar to below. I want to make just last row bold. Is it possible?

```
<table border = "5">
<?php
if (isset($startdate) && isset($enddate) ){
$query = "storedprocedure '$startdate','$enddate','field1'";
$result = mssql_query($query);
while ($rows = mssql_fetch_array($result) ) {
echo "<tr><td>".$rows[0]."&nbsp;<td>".$rows[1]."&nbsp;
<td>".$rows[2]."&nbsp;<td>".$rows[3]."&nbsp;
<td>".$rows[4]."&nbsp;<td>".$rows[5]."&nbsp;";
}
}
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML seems to be invalid

Comment: No, the same code works for me. Just I'm looking for bold in the last row.

Comment: Yes, it is. Calculate number of rows, instead of `while` use `for` loop where you can simply check if index is last.

Comment: The HTML is invalid - none of the opening `<td>` tags are closed; My answer corrects the output (hopefully).

Comment: @PLB He's using `mssql_*`, not `mysql_*`; The MSSQL functions are not deprecated.

Comment: @newfurniturey Oops, misread. Thanks, I'll edit my comment.

Comment: @newfurniture yes I just noticed that there is no </td> but it is still working. Thanks once again for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mssql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mssql_num_rows) to get the total number of rows returned by the query before you loop through them, and then (with the use of a counter), see if the current row is the last one and then apply any styling you want:

```
<table border = "5">
<?php
if (isset($startdate) && isset($enddate) ){
    $query = "storedprocedure '$startdate','$enddate','field1'";
    $result = mssql_query($query);
    $numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
    if ($numRows > 0) {
        $counter = 0;
        while ($rows = mssql_fetch_array($result) ) {
            $style = ($counter++ == ($numRows - 1)) ? ' style="font-weight: bold;"' : '';
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td<?=$style;?>><?=$rows[0];?></td>
                <td<?=$style;?>><?=$rows[1];?></td>
                <td<?=$style;?>><?=$rows[2];?></td>
                <td<?=$style;?>><?=$rows[3];?></td>
                <td<?=$style;?>><?=$rows[4];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?
        }
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that copying the data to an array (or better yet object) is much better, then outputting the data at the end makes these sorts of things easier.

in this case, if you drop the data into an array, you can then use lovely things like `count()` to see how many rows there are etc. This lets you do a simple check in the display loop to see if it is the last element in the array.

This should work:

```
<?php
if (isset($startdate) && isset($enddate))
{
    $res=array();
    $query = "storedprocedure '$startdate','$enddate','field1'";
    $result = mssql_query($query);
    while ($rows = mssql_fetch_array($result) ) 
    {
        $res[]=$rows;
    }
}
?>

<table border = "5" id="1">
<?php
    $numberRows=count(%res);
    for($i=0;$i<$numberRows;$i++)
    {
        $boldStart="";
        $boldEnd="";
        if($i==($numberRows-1))
        {
            $boldStart="<B>";
            $boldEnd="</B>";
        }
        echo "<tr><td>".$boldStart.$rows[$i][0].$boldEnd."&nbsp;</td><td>".$boldStart.$rows[$i][1].$boldEnd."&nbsp;
        </td><td>".$boldStart.$rows[$i][2].$boldEnd."&nbsp;</td><td>".$boldStart.$rows[$i][3].$boldEnd."&nbsp;
        </td><td>".$boldStart.$rows[$i][4].$boldEnd."&nbsp;</td><td>".$boldStart.$rows[$i][5].$boldEnd."&nbsp;</td>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the first thing came in my mind as solution but it's actually bad for memory management. It would be better if you use `mssql_num_rows` to calculate number of rows and then simply check in while loop. This solution has two advantages: 1. you write less code. 2. you don't allocate not needed memory.

Comment: @PLB Yeah, it's not perfect, but I do normally dump everything I will need later into objects and unset them after they aren't needed. That and I mainly make business apps for a low number of users, so I can take it easy with memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS:

t1 tr:last-child{font-weight:bold;}

Comment: Hi, @Wurstbro
I tried yours but it didn't work.
I added `<style type = "text/css"> .t1 {td:last-child{font-weight:bold;}` under head tag
Then in table tag i included the class like `<table class="t1">`

Comment: `.t1 td:last-child{font-weight:bold;}`

Comment: This just makes last column bold, not last row.....still it was useful. Thanks. Is there any similar css to make last row bold?

Comment: ah sorry for that .t1 tr:last-child{font-weight:bold;}